# loadAd method InterstitialAd in separate thread

Tags: android, admob

I have no idea what to do. I am trying to use interstitial ad in my app, but I can't perform loadAd method in UI thread this causes lags. I have no idea how to deal with this problem. Please suggest something. I would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

`InterstitialAd.loadAd()` performs the load in the background. It should no negligible impact on the UI thread. Measure the time it takes for `loadAd()` to execute.

Comment: By just calling loadAd it lags the UI very significantly, as oppose to our belief that it performs the load in background..

Comment: `loadAd()` performs no UI related activity. It downloads the ads from the network.

Comment: that was what I thought, until I see the significant lag. Haven't try to time it using code though